# Largest dimension of irreducible representation of crystallographic point group

Tags: solid-state-physics, group-theory, group-representations, crystals

I have studied crystallographic space group, say $G_{0}$, and found that any irreducible representation of $G_{0}$ has a dimension lower than or equal to 3.

I think that 3 is the very reasonable number in this case because we can construct a faithful representation of 3-dimensional $G_{0}$ on a vector space with at least 3-dimension.
Thus, I thought that there should be a theorem about the largest dimension of an irreducible representation of $G_{0}$, say $D$, and the least dimension of vector space required to construct a faithful representation, say $D$. However, I have failed in finding such a theorem.

Now, my question is...
Is there any statement or theorem about the relation between $d$ and $D$ for $G_{0}$??